# npm install failing with error "error Build failed with error code: 1"

Tags: node.js, webpack, caching, registry, npm-install

i am running npm install command on my project but getting error

> Build failed with error code: 1

Part of the log posted below.

```
0 verbose cli [
0 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
0 verbose cli   'C:\\Users\\vined\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
0 verbose cli   'install'
0 verbose cli ]
1 info using npm@8.0.0
2 info using node@v16.9.1
3 timing npm:load:whichnode Completed in 1ms
4 timing config:load:defaults Completed in 5ms
5 timing config:load:file:C:\Users\vined\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\npmrc Completed in 7ms
6 timing config:load:builtin Completed in 7ms
7 timing config:load:cli Completed in 6ms
8 timing config:load:env Completed in 1ms
9 timing config:load:file:E:\plugin-applepay-master\.npmrc Completed in 1ms
10 timing config:load:project Completed in 9ms
11 timing config:load:file:C:\Users\vined\.npmrc Completed in 2ms
12 timing config:load:user Completed in 3ms
13 timing config:load:file:C:\Users\vined\AppData\Roaming\npm\etc\npmrc Completed in 0ms
14 timing config:load:global Completed in 1ms
15 timing config:load:validate Completed in 5ms
16 timing config:load:credentials Completed in 3ms
17 timing config:load:setEnvs Completed in 3ms
18 timing config:load Completed in 43ms
19 timing npm:load:configload Completed in 43ms
20 timing npm:load:setTitle Completed in 6ms
21 timing npm:load:setupLog Completed in 1ms
22 timing config:load:flatten Completed in 11ms
23 timing npm:load:cleanupLog Completed in 8ms
24 timing npm:load:configScope Completed in 0ms
25 timing npm:load:projectScope Completed in 2ms
26 timing npm:load Completed in 76ms
27 timing arborist:ctor Completed in 3ms
28 timing idealTree:init Completed in 3609ms
29 warn old lockfile The package-lock.json file was created with an old version of npm,
29 warn old lockfile so supplemental metadata must be fetched from the registry.
29 warn old lockfile
29 warn old lockfile This is a one-time fix-up, please be patient...
30 silly inflate node_modules/@tridnguyen/config
31 silly inflate node_modules/@webassemblyjs/ast
32 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/@webassemblyjs%2Fast 891ms (cache revalidated)
33 silly inflate node_modules/@webassemblyjs/floating-point-hex-parser
34 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/@webassemblyjs%2Ffloating-point-hex-parser 153ms (cache revalidated)
35 silly inflate node_modules/@webassemblyjs/helper-api-error
36 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/@webassemblyjs%2Fhelper-api-error 155ms (cache revalidated)
37 silly inflate node_modules/@webassemblyjs/helper-buffer
38 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/@webassemblyjs%2Fhelper-buffer 184ms (cache revalidated)
39 silly inflate node_modules/@webassemblyjs/helper-code-frame
40 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/@webassemblyjs%2Fhelper-code-frame 115ms (cache revalidated)
3313 timing reifyNode:node_modules/events Completed in 56407ms
3314 timing reifyNode:node_modules/optimist Completed in 56748ms
3315 timing reifyNode:node_modules/es6-map Completed in 56420ms
3316 timing reifyNode:node_modules/argparse Completed in 56262ms
3317 timing reifyNode:node_modules/dwupload/node_modules/yargs Completed in 56467ms
3318 timing reifyNode:node_modules/iconv-lite Completed in 56651ms
3319 timing reifyNode:node_modules/stylelint/node_modules/table Completed in 57303ms
3320 timing reifyNode:node_modules/public-encrypt Completed in 57110ms
3321 timing reifyNode:node_modules/source-map Completed in 57327ms
3322 timing reifyNode:node_modules/cacache Completed in 56598ms
3323 timing reifyNode:node_modules/uglify-js Completed in 57809ms
3324 timing reifyNode:node_modules/terser/node_modules/source-map Completed in 57789ms
3325 timing reifyNode:node_modules/stylelint/node_modules/source-map Completed in 57764ms
3326 timing reifyNode:node_modules/terser-webpack-plugin/node_modules/source-map Completed in 57799ms
3327 timing reifyNode:node_modules/uglify-js/node_modules/source-map Completed in 57833ms
3328 timing reifyNode:node_modules/postcss-reporter/node_modules/source-map Completed in 57525ms
3329 timing reifyNode:node_modules/postcss-sass/node_modules/source-map Completed in 57540ms
3330 timing reifyNode:node_modules/webpack-sources/node_modules/source-map Completed in 58016ms
3331 timing reifyNode:node_modules/postcss-loader/node_modules/source-map Completed in 57507ms
3332 timing reifyNode:node_modules/dom-serializer/node_modules/entities Completed in 57096ms
3333 timing reifyNode:node_modules/postcss-modules-values/node_modules/source-map Completed in 57555ms
3334 timing reifyNode:node_modules/sugarss/node_modules/source-map Completed in 57841ms
3335 timing reifyNode:node_modules/postcss-modules-scope/node_modules/source-map Completed in 57565ms
3336 timing reifyNode:node_modules/postcss-modules-extract-imports/node_modules/source-map Completed in 57556ms
3337 timing reifyNode:node_modules/postcss-safe-parser/node_modules/source-map Completed in 57598ms
3338 timing reifyNode:node_modules/postcss-scss/node_modules/source-map Completed in 57615ms
3339 timing reifyNode:node_modules/postcss-modules-local-by-default/node_modules/source-map Completed in 57573ms
3340 timing reifyNode:node_modules/css/node_modules/source-map Completed in 57087ms
3341 timing reifyNode:node_modules/handlebars/node_modules/source-map Completed in 57240ms
3342 timing reifyNode:node_modules/icss-utils/node_modules/source-map Completed in 57289ms
3343 timing reifyNode:node_modules/source-map-support/node_modules/source-map Completed in 57832ms
3344 timing reifyNode:node_modules/stylelint-scss/node_modules/postcss-selector-parser Completed in 58076ms
3345 timing reifyNode:node_modules/stylelint/node_modules/postcss-selector-parser Completed in 58064ms
3346 timing reifyNode:node_modules/schema-utils/node_modules/ajv-keywords Completed in 58034ms
3347 timing reifyNode:node_modules/stylelint/node_modules/ajv-keywords Completed in 58129ms
3348 timing reifyNode:node_modules/webpack/node_modules/ajv-keywords Completed in 58363ms
3349 timing reifyNode:node_modules/terser-webpack-plugin/node_modules/ajv-keywords Completed in 58232ms
3350 timing reifyNode:node_modules/domhandler Completed in 57567ms
3351 timing reifyNode:node_modules/json-schema Completed in 58264ms
3352 timing reifyNode:node_modules/stream-http Completed in 59326ms
3353 timing reifyNode:node_modules/diff Completed in 59764ms
3354 timing reifyNode:node_modules/pako Completed in 60450ms
3355 timing reifyNode:node_modules/es6-set Completed in 60124ms
3356 timing reifyNode:node_modules/@webassemblyjs/ast Completed in 59888ms
3357 timing reifyNode:node_modules/sshpk Completed in 60786ms
3358 timing reifyNode:node_modules/js-yaml Completed in 60636ms
3359 timing reifyNode:node_modules/terser Completed in 61207ms
3360 timing reifyNode:node_modules/cosmiconfig/node_modules/js-yaml Completed in 60646ms
3361 timing reifyNode:node_modules/stylelint/node_modules/js-yaml Completed in 61401ms
3362 timing reifyNode:node_modules/enhanced-resolve Completed in 60729ms
3363 timing reifyNode:node_modules/yargs Completed in 61701ms
3364 timing reifyNode:node_modules/shelljs Completed in 61498ms
3365 timing reifyNode:node_modules/escodegen/node_modules/source-map Completed in 61116ms
3366 timing reifyNode:node_modules/jszip Completed in 61402ms
3367 timing reifyNode:node_modules/postcss Completed in 61593ms
3368 timing reifyNode:node_modules/sgmf-scripts/node_modules/shelljs Completed in 61827ms
3369 timing reifyNode:node_modules/remark-stringify Completed in 61911ms
3370 timing reifyNode:node_modules/chai Completed in 61596ms
3371 timing reifyNode:node_modules/postcss-modules-values/node_modules/postcss Completed in 62197ms
3372 timing reifyNode:node_modules/postcss-scss/node_modules/postcss Completed in 62232ms
3373 timing reifyNode:node_modules/postcss-safe-parser/node_modules/postcss Completed in 62227ms
3374 timing reifyNode:node_modules/postcss-modules-scope/node_modules/postcss Completed in 62210ms
3375 timing reifyNode:node_modules/stylelint/node_modules/postcss Completed in 62474ms
3376 timing reifyNode:node_modules/postcss-modules-local-by-default/node_modules/postcss Completed in 62218ms
3377 timing reifyNode:node_modules/icss-utils/node_modules/postcss Completed in 61909ms
3378 timing reifyNode:node_modules/sugarss/node_modules/postcss Completed in 62507ms
3379 timing reifyNode:node_modules/postcss-modules-extract-imports/node_modules/postcss Completed in 62221ms
3380 timing reifyNode:node_modules/postcss-loader/node_modules/postcss Completed in 62209ms
3381 timing reifyNode:node_modules/postcss-sass/node_modules/postcss Completed in 62271ms
3382 timing reifyNode:node_modules/postcss-reporter/node_modules/postcss Completed in 62264ms
3383 warn deprecated buffer@4.9.1: This version of 'buffer' is out-of-date. You must update to v4.9.2 or newer
3384 timing reifyNode:node_modules/node-libs-browser/node_modules/buffer Completed in 62235ms
3385 timing reifyNode:node_modules/remark-parse Completed in 64660ms
3386 timing reifyNode:node_modules/nan Completed in 64578ms
3387 timing reifyNode:node_modules/bluebird Completed in 64116ms
3388 timing reifyNode:node_modules/sinon Completed in 64900ms
3389 timing reifyNode:node_modules/node-notifier Completed in 64751ms
3390 timing reifyNode:node_modules/proxyquire Completed in 64949ms
3391 timing reifyNode:node_modules/coa Completed in 64496ms
3392 timing reifyNode:node_modules/eslint-plugin-import Completed in 64649ms
3393 timing reifyNode:node_modules/cacache/node_modules/bluebird Completed in 64551ms
3394 timing reifyNode:node_modules/acorn-jsx/node_modules/acorn Completed in 64749ms
3395 timing reifyNode:node_modules/postcss-less Completed in 65491ms
3396 timing reifyNode:node_modules/csso Completed in 65141ms
3397 timing reifyNode:node_modules/table Completed in 66025ms
3398 timing reifyNode:node_modules/crc Completed in 65252ms
3399 timing reifyNode:node_modules/escope Completed in 65347ms
3400 timing reifyNode:node_modules/mocha Completed in 65706ms
3401 warn deprecated istanbul@0.4.5: This module is no longer maintained, try this instead:
3401 warn deprecated   npm i nyc
3401 warn deprecated Visit https://istanbul.js.org/integrations for other alternatives.
3402 timing reifyNode:node_modules/istanbul Completed in 65794ms
3403 timing reifyNode:node_modules/autoprefixer Completed in 65865ms
3404 warn deprecated svgo@0.7.2: This SVGO version is no longer supported. Upgrade to v2.x.x.
3405 timing reifyNode:node_modules/svgo Completed in 66839ms
3406 timing reifyNode:node_modules/uri-js Completed in 66975ms
3407 timing reifyNode:node_modules/sgmf-scripts Completed in 67253ms
3408 timing reifyNode:node_modules/stylelint/node_modules/autoprefixer Completed in 67610ms
3409 timing reifyNode:node_modules/istanbul/node_modules/resolve Completed in 68223ms
3410 timing reifyNode:node_modules/schema-utils/node_modules/ajv Completed in 70277ms
3411 timing reifyNode:node_modules/webpack/node_modules/ajv Completed in 70600ms
3412 timing reifyNode:node_modules/terser-webpack-plugin/node_modules/ajv Completed in 70472ms
3413 timing reifyNode:node_modules/har-validator/node_modules/ajv Completed in 69904ms
3414 timing reifyNode:node_modules/stylelint/node_modules/ajv Completed in 70477ms
3415 timing reifyNode:node_modules/resolve Completed in 70397ms
3416 warn deprecated tar@2.2.2: This version of tar is no longer supported, and will not receive security updates. Please upgrade asap.
3417 timing reifyNode:node_modules/tar Completed in 70821ms
3418 timing reifyNode:node_modules/ajv Completed in 70421ms
3419 timing reifyNode:node_modules/neo-async Completed in 70973ms
3420 timing reifyNode:node_modules/type Completed in 71535ms
3421 timing reifyNode:node_modules/node-gyp Completed in 71977ms
3422 timing reifyNode:node_modules/extract-text-webpack-plugin/node_modules/async Completed in 71756ms
3423 timing reifyNode:node_modules/archiver/node_modules/async Completed in 71520ms
3424 timing reifyNode:node_modules/handlebars Completed in 72430ms
3425 timing reifyNode:node_modules/stylelint-scss Completed in 74065ms
3426 timing reifyNode:node_modules/babel-runtime Completed in 75225ms
3427 timing reifyNode:node_modules/eslint Completed in 78354ms
3428 timing reifyNode:node_modules/webpack Completed in 79374ms
3429 timing reifyNode:node_modules/node-sass Completed in 79028ms
3430 warn deprecated webdriverio@4.14.4: outdated version, please use @next
3431 timing reifyNode:node_modules/webdriverio Completed in 86402ms
3432 timing reifyNode:node_modules/stylelint Completed in 86352ms
3433 timing reifyNode:node_modules/cleave.js Completed in 88431ms
3434 timing reifyNode:node_modules/caniuse-lite Completed in 89944ms
3435 timing reifyNode:node_modules/es5-ext Completed in 90823ms
3436 timing reifyNode:node_modules/caniuse-db Completed in 91715ms
3437 timing reifyNode:node_modules/lodash Completed in 92690ms
3438 warn deprecated core-js@2.6.10: core-js@<3.3 is no longer maintained and not recommended for usage due to the number of issues. Because of the V8 engine whims, feature detection in old core-js versions could cause a slowdown up to 100x even if nothing is polyfilled. Please, upgrade your dependencies to the actual version of core-js.
3439 timing reifyNode:node_modules/core-js Completed in 94192ms
3440 timing reify:unpack Completed in 95219ms
3441 timing reify:unretire Completed in 4ms
3442 timing build:queue Completed in 240ms
3443 timing build:link:node_modules/atob Completed in 596ms
3444 timing build:link:node_modules/acorn-jsx/node_modules/acorn Completed in 559ms
3445 timing build:link:node_modules/node-gyp/node_modules/semver Completed in 557ms
3446 timing build:link:node_modules/sass-loader/node_modules/semver Completed in 556ms
3447 timing build:link:node_modules/sgmf-scripts/node_modules/shelljs Completed in 555ms
3448 timing build:link:node_modules/stylelint/node_modules/autoprefixer Completed in 554ms
3449 timing build:link:node_modules/webpack/node_modules/acorn Completed in 552ms
3450 timing build:link:node_modules/acorn Completed in 607ms
3451 timing build:link:node_modules/browserslist Completed in 603ms
3452 timing build:link:node_modules/cssesc Completed in 602ms
3453 timing build:link:node_modules/csso Completed in 634ms
3454 timing build:link:node_modules/errno Completed in 634ms
3455 timing build:link:node_modules/escodegen Completed in 633ms
3456 timing build:link:node_modules/eslint Completed in 631ms
3457 timing build:link:node_modules/esprima Completed in 630ms
3458 timing build:link:node_modules/gonzales-pe Completed in 628ms
3459 timing build:link:node_modules/he Completed in 626ms
3460 timing build:link:node_modules/handlebars Completed in 627ms
3461 timing build:link:node_modules/in-publish Completed in 626ms
3462 timing build:link:node_modules/istanbul Completed in 624ms
3463 timing build:link:node_modules/js-yaml Completed in 623ms
3464 timing build:link:node_modules/jsesc Completed in 622ms
3465 timing build:link:node_modules/json5 Completed in 622ms
3466 timing build:link:node_modules/mkdirp Completed in 620ms
3467 timing build:link:node_modules/mocha Completed in 619ms
3468 timing build:link:node_modules/node-gyp Completed in 618ms
3469 timing build:link:node_modules/miller-rabin Completed in 620ms
3470 timing build:link:node_modules/node-sass Completed in 617ms
3471 timing build:link:node_modules/nopt Completed in 614ms
3472 timing build:link:node_modules/onchange Completed in 613ms
3473 timing build:link:node_modules/regjsparser Completed in 612ms
3474 timing build:link:node_modules/rimraf Completed in 611ms
3475 timing build:link:node_modules/sass-graph Completed in 611ms
3476 timing build:link:node_modules/semver Completed in 610ms
3477 timing build:link:node_modules/sgmf-scripts Completed in 609ms
3478 timing build:link:node_modules/sha.js Completed in 609ms
3479 timing build:link:node_modules/shelljs Completed in 608ms
3480 timing build:link:node_modules/specificity Completed in 607ms
3481 timing build:link:node_modules/sshpk Completed in 607ms
3482 timing build:link:node_modules/strip-indent Completed in 606ms
3483 timing build:link:node_modules/stylelint Completed in 605ms
3484 timing build:link:node_modules/svgo Completed in 604ms
3485 timing build:link:node_modules/terser Completed in 603ms
3486 timing build:link:node_modules/tree-kill Completed in 602ms
3487 timing build:link:node_modules/uglify-js Completed in 602ms
3488 timing build:link:node_modules/uuid Completed in 601ms
3489 timing build:link:node_modules/webdriverio Completed in 599ms
3490 timing build:link:node_modules/watch Completed in 600ms
3491 timing build:link:node_modules/webpack Completed in 598ms
3492 timing build:link:node_modules/which Completed in 597ms
3493 timing build:link:node_modules/window-size Completed in 597ms
3494 timing build:link:node_modules/cosmiconfig/node_modules/esprima Completed in 596ms
3495 timing build:link:node_modules/cosmiconfig/node_modules/js-yaml Completed in 594ms
3496 timing build:link:node_modules/stylelint/node_modules/browserslist Completed in 590ms
3497 timing build:link:node_modules/stylelint/node_modules/esprima Completed in 590ms
3498 timing build:link:node_modules/stylelint/node_modules/js-yaml Completed in 588ms
3499 timing build:link:node_modules/dwupload Completed in 885ms
3500 timing build:link Completed in 891ms
3501 info run node-sass@4.12.0 install node_modules/node-sass node scripts/install.js
3502 info run node-sass@4.12.0 install { code: 0, signal: null }
3503 timing build:run:install:node_modules/node-sass Completed in 2303ms
3504 timing build:run:install Completed in 2304ms
3505 info run core-js@2.6.10 postinstall node_modules/core-js node postinstall || echo "ignore"
3506 info run node-sass@4.12.0 postinstall node_modules/node-sass node scripts/build.js
3507 info run core-js@2.6.10 postinstall { code: 0, signal: null }
3508 timing build:run:postinstall:node_modules/core-js Completed in 822ms
3509 info run node-sass@4.12.0 postinstall { code: 1, signal: null }
3510 timing reify:rollback:createSparse Completed in 23958ms
3511 timing reify:rollback:retireShallow Completed in 0ms
3512 timing command:install Completed in 265527ms
3513 verbose stack Error: command failed
3513 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Users\vined\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\@npmcli\promise-spawn\index.js:64:27)
3513 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:394:28)
3513 verbose stack     at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1064:16)
3513 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:301:5)
3514 verbose pkgid node-sass@4.12.0
3515 verbose cwd E:\plugin-applepay-master
3516 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.19043
3517 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\vined\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install"
3518 verbose node v16.9.1
3519 verbose npm  v8.0.0
3520 error code 1
3521 error path E:\plugin-applepay-master\node_modules\node-sass
3522 error command failed
3523 error command C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c node scripts/build.js
3524 error Building: C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe E:\plugin-applepay-master\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js rebuild --verbose --libsass_ext= --libsass_cflags= --libsass_ldflags= --libsass_library=
3525 error gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
3525 error gyp verb cli [
3525 error gyp verb cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
3525 error gyp verb cli   'E:\\plugin-applepay-master\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js',
3525 error gyp verb cli   'rebuild',
3525 error gyp verb cli   '--verbose',
3525 error gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ext=',
3525 error gyp verb cli   '--libsass_cflags=',
3525 error gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ldflags=',
3525 error gyp verb cli   '--libsass_library='
3525 error gyp verb cli ]
3525 error gyp info using node-gyp@3.8.0
3525 error gyp info using node@16.9.1 | win32 | x64
3525 error gyp verb command rebuild []
3525 error gyp verb command clean []
3525 error gyp verb clean removing "build" directory
3525 error gyp verb command configure []
3525 error gyp verb check python checking for Python executable "python2" in the PATH
3525 error gyp verb `which` failed Error: not found: python2
3525 error gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError (E:\plugin-applepay-master\node_modules\which\which.js:13:12)
3525 error gyp verb `which` failed     at F (E:\plugin-applepay-master\node_modules\which\which.js:68:19)
3525 error gyp verb `which` failed     at E (E:\plugin-applepay-master\node_modules\which\which.js:80:29)
3525 error gyp verb `which` failed     at E:\plugin-applepay-master\node_modules\which\which.js:89:16
3525 error gyp verb `which` failed     at E:\plugin-applepay-master\node_modules\isexe\index.js:42:5
3525 error gyp verb `which` failed     at E:\plugin-applepay-master\node_modules\isexe\windows.js:36:5
3525 error gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (node:fs:198:21)
3525 error gyp verb `which` failed  python2 Error: not found: python2
3525 error gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError (E:\plugin-applepay-master\node_modules\which\which.js:13:12)
3525 error gyp verb `which` failed     at F (E:\plugin-applepay-master\node_modules\which\which.js:68:19)
3525 error gyp verb `which` failed     at E (E:\plugin-applepay-master\node_modules\which\which.js:80:29)
3525 error gyp verb `which` failed     at E:\plugin-applepay-master\node_modules\which\which.js:89:16
3525 error gyp verb `which` failed     at E:\plugin-applepay-master\node_modules\isexe\index.js:42:5
3525 error gyp verb `which` failed     at E:\plugin-applepay-master\node_modules\isexe\windows.js:36:5
3525 error gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (node:fs:198:21) {
3525 error gyp verb `which` failed   code: 'ENOENT'
3525 error gyp verb `which` failed }
3525 error gyp verb check python checking for Python executable "python" in the PATH
3525 error gyp verb `which` succeeded python C:\Python310\python.EXE
3525 error gyp ERR! configure error
3525 error gyp ERR! stack Error: Command failed: C:\Python310\python.EXE -c import sys; print "%s.%s.%s" % sys.version_info[:3];
3525 error gyp ERR! stack   File "<string>", line 1
3525 error gyp ERR! stack     import sys; print "%s.%s.%s" % sys.version_info[:3];
3525 error gyp ERR! stack                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
3525 error gyp ERR! stack SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'. Did you mean print(...)?
3525 error gyp ERR! stack
3525 error gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.exithandler (node:child_process:397:12)
3525 error gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:394:28)
3525 error gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1064:16)
3525 error gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:301:5)
3525 error gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.19043
3525 error gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "E:\\plugin-applepay-master\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--verbose" "--libsass_ext=" "--libsass_cflags=" "--libsass_ldflags=" "--libsass_library="
3525 error gyp ERR! cwd E:\plugin-applepay-master\node_modules\node-sass
3525 error gyp ERR! node -v v16.9.1
3525 error gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
3525 error gyp ERR! not ok
3525 error Build failed with error code: 1
3526 verbose exit 1
```

******Below is my package.Json******

```
{
  "name": "plugin_applepay",
  "version": "6.0.0",
  "description": "ApplePay plugin for Storefront Reference Architecture",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "sgmf-scripts --test",
    "compile:scss": "sgmf-scripts --compile css",
    "compile:js": "sgmf-scripts --compile js",
    "build": "npm run compile:js && npm run compile:scss",
    "upload": "sgmf-scripts --upload",
    "uploadCartridge": "sgmf-scripts --uploadCartridge plugin_applepay",
    "lint": "sgmf-scripts --lint js && sgmf-scripts --lint css"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/SalesforceCommerceCloud/plugin-applepay.git"
  },
  "author": "Ilya Volodin <ivolodin@demandware.com>",
  "license": "MIT",
  "homepage": "https://github.com/SalesforceCommerceCloud/plugin-applepay",
  "devDependencies": {
    "chai": "^3.5.0",
    "cleave.js": "1.5.0",
    "css-loader": "^0.28.11",
    "eslint": "^3.19.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb-base": "^5.0.3",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^1.16.0",
    "mocha": "^5.2.0",
    "mocha-junit-reporter": "^1.12.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.12.0",
    "postcss-loader": "^2.1.6",
    "proxyquire": "1.7.4",
    "sass-loader": "^7.3.1",
    "sgmf-scripts": "^2.3.0",
    "shelljs": "^0.7.7",
    "sinon": "^1.17.7",
    "stylelint": "^8.4.0",
    "stylelint-config-standard": "^17.0.0",
    "stylelint-scss": "^2.5.0"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    "last 2 versions",
    "ie >= 10"
  ],
  "paths": {
    "base": "../storefront-reference-architecture/cartridges/app_storefront_base/"
  }
}
```

It was working fine till 15 days back. I had re-installed my windows and it stopped working any think to do with windows ENV variable.

Comment: Looks like you no longer have the `python2` executable set as a part of your environment variable `Path` like it used to be previously. It is not working because your computer is trying to use your the Python 3 executable it did find in the `Path`. You could try installing a version of Python 2 from say here: https://www.python.org/downloads/ and set it in your `Path` to make it work again.

Answer (score 0):

> 3525 error gyp verb check python checking for Python executable "python2" in the PATH

Looks like the cause may be that one module expects to be built with Python 2.x but you only have Python 3.x installed. Also possible you have Python 2.x installed but it is not exposed in your PATH variable.

Comment: currently i have python 3.10.0 version installed on my windows

Comment: Yes, so try installing python 2.x and retry.

Answer (score 0):

`error gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0`

For python v3.x please upgrade node-gyp to a version greater than 5.0.5: https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp/releases

See:

- https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp/issues/1687
- https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp/issues/1337 (slim-hmidi has the same error)